# lower bound and upper bound of expression ($1-\frac{1}{n})^{\log n}$

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

Let's say that $f(n)=\bigl(\frac{n-1}{n}\bigr)^{\log n}$ ( I know bounds of  $\bigl(\frac{n-1}{n}\bigr)^{n}$ ).

Is there any way I can get good upper bound of $f(n)$ when n is positive?

Thanks in advance

Comment: bounds for what sort of $n$?

Comment: when n is positive

Comment: Huh?  For example, which $\log(1/2)$-power of $-1$? (when $n=\frac12>0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \leq \frac{1}{e} \leq \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n-1}.
$$

Then
$$
\log f(n) = \log n \cdot \log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \leq -\frac{\log n}{n}
$$
and
$$
\log f(n) = \log n \cdot \log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \geq -\frac{\log n}{n-1},
$$
hence
$$
\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}} \leq f(n) \leq \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

For  $n>1$, $\;0<1-\dfrac1n<1\;$ and $\; \log n>0$, so
$$\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^{\log n}<\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^0=1.$$
Furthermore, the limit of $f(n)$ isqual to $1$:
$$f(n)=\mathrm e^{\log n\,\log\bigl(1-\tfrac1n\bigr)}=\mathrm e^{\log n\bigl(-\tfrac1n+o\bigl(\tfrac1n\bigr)\bigr)}=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{\log n}n+o\bigl(\tfrac{\log n}n\bigr)}\to\mathrm e^0.$$