# Simple statement in the elementary proof of the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma (random projections)

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, random, projection

In the simple proof of the johnson lindenstrauss lemma written by Sanjoy Dasgupta, Anupam Gupta that can be found [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Edasgupta/papers/jl.pdf) they state the following (p.$62$):

> Repeating this projection $O(n)$ times can boost the success probability to the desired constant, giving us the claimed randomized polynomial time algorithm.

My idea is to see that the success probability of a single trial is $1/n$ thus the success probability of atleast one trial out of $n$ trials is $1 - (1/n)^n$ if we then set it to be larger than $0.95$ we end up with:
$0.05 > (1 - 1/n)^n$ thus $\log(0.05) > n\log(1 - 1/n)$ but i think this way of proving it is wrong.

I would really like to understand why the statement is true.

Could someone help me bring some clarity into this?

Comment: The probability of at least one success in $n$ trials should be $1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$.

Comment: yeah, fixed. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: I think this inequality might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2936463/364346

Comment: seems promising but im still not able to derive it

Answer (score 1):

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-) that $$1+x \leq e^x$$ for all real $x$.

If we run $cn$ independent trials, where $c$ is some constant, the probability of at least one success is

$$1-(1-P(\text{success}))^{cn}\geq 1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{cn}\geq1-e^{-c},$$

where the last line follows from the original inequality, letting $x=-\frac{1}{n}$.

For $c$ large enough, we can make the probability of at least one success as close to $1$ as we like, and this only requires $cn\in O(n)$ trials.